# C++ CLI Passing an array to class

Tags: c++-cli

As the title says I have to create class that can accept arrays as a parameter.

Here is my current version of the header file:

```
public ref class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass() {};  
    MyClass(array<int, 2> ^(&A1), const int &i2) : A1(A1), I2(i2) {};
    String^ Method(); 
    ~MyClass() {};

private: 
    array<int, 2>^ A1 = gcnew array<int, 2>(3, 3) {
        { 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1 },
    };  
    int I2 = 5;  
};

String^ MyClass::Method() // Simple output for debugging 
{
    String^ OutputText;
    int sum=10;
    OutputText= "OutputText = " + sum;
    return OutputText;
}
```

As of now I'm getting the following error:

> '$S1': global or static variable may not have managed type
>   'cli::array ^'

If I change my array to static I'll get:

> "A1" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "MyClass"

Class has to have both constructors. I can accept a solution with vector, but i experience pretty much the same issues with it.

Comment: Move the initializtion of `A1` array in a constructor.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko Thanks for your suggestion, but I didn't understand where exactly to move the initializtion. I kept the `array<int, 2>^ A1 = gcnew array<int, 2>(3, 3);` removing the { } part. This solved errors, however now I'm curious how to add values to A1 in case default constructor is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant under moving the initialization of the array to a constructor:

```
public ref class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass() {
        A1 = gcnew array<int, 2>(3, 3) {
                { 1, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1 },
            };  
    };  
    MyClass(array<int, 2> ^(&A1), const int &i2) : A1(A1), I2(i2) {};
    String^ Method(); 
    ~MyClass() {};

private: 
    array<int, 2>^ A1;  
    int I2 = 5;  
};
```